# Laravel: How to get easily values from table with polymorphic relations eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.6

I have employees list in my database table:

**Table:** Employees

[image]

**Employee model code:**

```php
public function workplace()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Company model code:**

```php
public function workers()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Employee', 'company');
}
```

**Branch model code:**

```php
public function workers()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Employee', 'company');
}
```

Now I get user worklaces in sample different form:

```php
$userWorkplaces = Employee::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
$workplace_info = [];

foreach ($userWorkplaces as $workplace) {
    if($workplace->company_type == "App\Company") {
        $company = Company::findOrFail($workplace->company_id);
        $type = 'Company';
    } elseif($workplace->company_type == "App\Branch") {
        $company = Branch::findOrFail($workplace->company_id);
        $type = 'Branch';
    }

    $workplace_info[] = [
        'company' => $company->name,
        'type' => $type
    ];
}

dump($workplace_info);
```

**Result:**

```php
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "company" => "Mahorat"
    "type" => "Company"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "company" => "Babolo"
    "type" => "Company"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "company" => "Филиал Махорат"
    "type" => "Branch"
  ]
]
```

How I can get easyly sample result by creating laravel relationships in models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change in your `Employee` relationship function name `company` because you have `company_id` and `company_type` fields in employee table

**Employee model code:**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Now fetch data**

```
$employees = Employee::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
$workplace_info = [];
foreach($employees as $employee){
   $workplace_info[]['company'] = $employee->company;
   $workplace_info[]['type'] = get_class($employee->company);
}

dd($workplace_info);
```

Details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: When I change my code to your demo code var `$employees` return all results from `Employee` model table but insite loop return `null` result always. @rkj

Comment: @Otabek there was mistake need to change the relationship name to `company` in Employee model and same as  yours for other model. i have updated answer please try again, should work now

Comment: Ok, now it is return 2 row from Company model and 1 row from Branch model. How I can get row model type (Company or Branch) here? @rkj

Comment: you have model object, now you can use php `get_class' to get its model name with namespace